# NAudio ASIO Playback wav

Tags: c#, naudio, sharpdevelop, asio

I'm using NAudio and ASIO to play a sequence of wav files. I need to use ASIO because the audio card supports only that. I was able to play each wav in this way:

```
     waveRead = new WaveFileReader(completeStreamMS); //completeStreamMS is a memorystream
     waveRead.Position = 0;
     pcm = new WaveChannel32(waveRead);
     reductionStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
     reductionStream.Position = 0;
     waveOutDevice.Init(reductionStream);
     waveOutDevice.Play();
```

Now I need to insert 1 second of silent before the starting of the wav. The only way I found is to use an OffsetSampleProvider, but if I do like this

```
     ISampleProvider isp = WaveExtensionMethods.ToSampleProvider(waveRead);
     var offset = new SampleProviders.OffsetSampleProvider(isp);
     offset.DelayBy = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
     var wp = new SampleProviders.SampleToWaveProvider(offset);
     waveOutDevice.Init(wp);`
     waveOutDevice.Play();
```

The first wav plays just fine, but as soon as I stop() the waveOutDevice or I try to reinstantiate a new one the execution of the program stops at that position with

```
System.ExecutionEngineException
Cannot intercept exception. Debugged program can not be continued and properties can not be evaluated.
```

I'm not able to understand why. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with ASIO, it is better to just open the output device once, leave it playing and then change its input. You could for example add and remove items from a `MixingSampleProvider` used as input.